# What is the difference between args and argh and argv in Java?

Tags: java, argv, args, argh

While practicing some questions on hackerrank, some of the solutions had argh instead of args (which I have used mostly). Also, I got to know that there is another such argument that can be passed to main() function and that is argv. Thus in all there are three different arguments that exist:

args

argh

argv

Could you please tell me the difference between all three and how and when to use them?

And here is the code:

```
class Solution{
public static void main(String []argh){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        String name = in.next();
        int phone = in.nextInt();
        // Write code here
    }
    while(in.hasNext()){
        String s = in.next();
        // Write code here
    }
    in.close();
  }
}
```

*Please note that I am not asking for the solution to the above question. I have already solved it and made a successful submission but what I wanted to know was what difference would it make by adding argh instead of args?*

*thanks in advance!*

Comment: It's the same argument, no matter how you call it.

Comment: There is no difference, they are just different names, you can name them as you like, but those are the more common ones

Comment: `args` is the Java convention. `argv` is used in C and C++ and so might be used by an idiosyncratic Java programmer who wishes they were using the languages from the good old days. Using `argh` is the work of a wierdo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java function signatures are validated based on their return and arguments types, but never check for the name of the arguments. This means that

```
public static void main(String... parameters) { /* [...] */ }
```

is a valid `main` function.

It also means that you don't have to use the same argument names as an interface when implementing its functions, or as a class you extend when overloading its functions.